# What happends when Android locked and the unlocked?

Tags: android

What methods of `Activity`,`Fragment` lifecycle should I use when lock and unlock my phone?
`onPause()` and `onResume()`?
Because at some Samsung phones I came accross the problem that when I firstly put my app to tray some way and then reopen it with app icon it reopens with StartActivity - not that I was

Comment: Reffer this http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-activity

Comment: When phone is locked, `onPause()` is called .. when its unlocked.. and supposing your activity was in foreground before it was locked, then `onResume()` will be called..

Comment: Lock, or just screen on/off?

Comment: @weston Could you please provide both answers

Comment: @KirillZotov the activity/Fragment workflow is no different than if you were to hit the home button in your app

Answer (score 1):

When you locked the screen the activity get paused and then over the time it stoped working , but it depends on androidt to destroy it or not , let suppose it is not doing the hectic work and not using so much resources of the android 
then it would simply use 
1. On pause
2 On Stop (in case of you stopped your activity before going into sleep or android life cycle does or any other condition)

and when unlocking

1. On resume
2. On ReStart (In case of activity stooped first)

I think it is quite clear with the possibilities which could have happen in your case , according to your question.

Now if you are wondering what is difference between on Pause and Stop and then it is called , just consider the following definition

> the paused state, which identifies a partial UI obstruction, the
>   stopped state guarantees that the UI is no longer visible and the
>   user's focus is in a separate activity (or an entirely separate app).

and here is the link  about [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html) discussion.